# Can we declared ,defined or initilization or take user input of an array elements in a GUI java?

Tags: java, user-interface, graphical-programming

Can we declare or initialize or take user input values of arrays in GUI Java only in one frame ??
If yes then how? and no then reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes with the following code

```
`import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.util.Arrays;


 public class ArrayInGUI {

     static int[] array;
     public static void main(String[] args) {

         JFrame frame=new JFrame("Arrays");
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

         JLabel label=new JLabel("Enter indexes");
         JLabel label1=new JLabel("  Enter array with , sep");
         JLabel label2=new JLabel();

         JTextField field=new JTextField(16);
         JTextField field1=new JTextField(16);

         JButton button=new JButton("OK");
         JButton button1=new JButton("Ok print");

         JPanel panel=new JPanel();
         panel.add(label);
         panel.add(field);
         panel.add(button);
         panel.add(label1);
         panel.add(field1);
         panel.add(button1);
         panel.add(label2);


         button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
             @Override
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 array=new int[Integer.parseInt(field.getText())];
             }
         });
         button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
             @Override
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                 String s = field1.getText();

                 String[] copy = s.split(",");

                 if (copy.length == array.length) {
                     for (int i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
                         array[i] = Integer.parseInt(copy[i]);
                     }

                     label2.setText("   " + Arrays.toString(array));
                 } else {
                     label2.setText("Error please enter" + array.length + "   element");
                 }
             }
         });

         frame.add(panel);
         frame.setSize(200,300);
         frame.show();

     }

 }`
```